# is there a "goto" like command in ksh

Tags: shell-script, ksh, control-flow

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#this is where I want to go again if user enter 
#an answer other than "yes or no"

echo "yes or no?"
read ans

case $ans in

    [yY]*)
        echo "yes"
        ;;

    [nN]*)
        echo "no"
        ;;

    *)
        echo "yes or no only"
        # here, if the answer is not "Y" or "N", 
        # I want to go back to asking "yes or no?"
        ;;
esac
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could put the `read` and your `case` in a `while` loop and `break` out of it when the condition is satisfied:

```
while : ; do
  echo "yes or no?"
  read ans

  case $ans in
    [yY]*)
        echo "yes"
        break
        ;;
    [nN]*)
        echo "no"
        break
        ;;
    *)
        echo "yes or no only"
        ;;
  esac
done
```

The `while : ; do ... done` represents an infinite loop.  `break` exits a `for`, `while`, or `until` loop.  Use `break` to exit in case the answer is `y` or `n`, else the loop would continue.